# $(this).focus() not working when textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

My following code is not setting focus on textbox when it is when it is empty:

```
var empty = false;

$('.Newtxt').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
        $(this).focus();
        empty = true;
    }
});

if (empty) {
    return false;
}
```

Can we set focus on `$(this)` element? I have multiple textbox which needs to be validated with `.Newtxt` class.

Comment: Your code isn't using `focus()`?

Comment: Can you provide your DOM structure please? Also there is no .focus() in your code... ?

Comment: In addition to there being no `focus()` in your code, even if there was, you couldn't do it in that example...you'd be trying to set the focus on each element with a `Newtxt` class -- you can't set the focus of potentially `n` elements.

Comment: Ohh.. I forgot to put $(this).focus() .. now I have edited it ... can we do $(this).focus()

Comment: In your context .focus() apply for last invalid textbox right

Comment: you have any class for user enter invalid option or empty

Comment: Yes multiple textbox could be empty/invalid... in that case focus should be on first textbox..

Comment: In that time you add any class how you find the field empty/invalid

Comment: So then just add `break;`...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var empty = false;

$('.Newtxt').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
        $(this).focus();
        empty = true;
        break; // add this, you have to break cycle, to focus on the first found empty element...
    }
});

if (empty) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `break` is not a valid way to exit an `each` function. That is for JavaScript loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$('.Newtxt').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
        $(this).focus();
        return false; // To break out of each loop
    }
});
```

ENjoy!!

Comment: It cannot go for next textbox

Comment: Obviously!! Focus should be on the first empty one!!? He can run it again on the next focusOut event on that class..

Comment: no he said all validation should be way out. on the first invalid fileld focus will apply

Comment: Yes, exactly what I am trying to say!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found one solution. Try that and let me know

```
$('.Newtxt').removeClass('invalid');
$('.Newtxt').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
        $(this).addClass('invalid');
        empty = true;
    }
});

if (empty) {
    $(".invalid").eq(0).focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you are genius gurunatha

Comment: but it wont work in second time bcoz you did not remove that invalid class,, r u got my point

Comment: you have to use **$('.Newtxt').removeClass('invalid ')** before each function

Comment: @Balachandran - Thanks for your valid comment